# max_user_connections or ip connection limit exceeded

Tags: web-hosting, php

I am getting following "PHP Error Message" :

User ****** already has more than 'max_user_connections' active connections in /home/*****//***** on line 6 or

for my website www.****.com, and this error goes after reloading the page for 3-4 times. Earlier this error was not coming. So can somebody tell me whether this error relates to PHP or DB.

i am using freehosting like 1freehosting.com or 000webhost.com

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9389201/max-user-connections-set-to-200-still-getting-error

Comment: The error comes from MySQL, the reason is that it does not allow enough simultaneous connections to the database to satisfy what your app needs. Beyond that, without more info it's anyone's guess what setting or code that causes it.

Comment: Your code may opening the connection to the database, but not closing it. If so here is an article(http://w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp) with more information about closing your database connections.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You receive max_user_connections message when the maximum number of users allowed to connect the server are already there.

Here are the links for your references
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_user_connections 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/too-many-connections.html

You can either increase the number of connections allowed or 
Instead of opening new connection for everyone. Why dont you use same connection for all queries.

Comment: how to increase  the number of connection or if i moved to dedicated hosting will this problem solve.

Comment: max_user_connection can be found in database: mysql, table: user

Comment: Dedicated hosting will definitely have more power to handle higher number users. Make the decision on your future analysis.

Comment: you said that Why dont you use same connection for all queries. how will do that?