# User 'xxxxxx' has exceeded the 'max_user_connections or Too many connections errors

Tags: php, mysqli

My pages can have up to 7 different queries on any one page. I would normally open a mysqli connection at the top of my page and maybe naughtily allow PHP to close the mysqli connection once the script has executed, but I'm currently experiencing **User 'xxxxxx' has exceeded the 'max_user_connections** or **Too many connections** errors.

My question is: If I have 7 different queries on a single page, should I be opening and closing a connection for each query, rather than allowing a connection at the top of the page and closing it at the bottom of my page?

I use a connection at the top of the page and then allow PHP to close the connection once the PHP script has executed.

```
$dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'xxxx', 'xxx', 'xxx') 
or die('Error connecting to MySQL server Home.');
```

and then up to 7 queries throughout the page as per below

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM xxxx ORDER BY xxx_id DESC LIMIT 1';

$results = mysqli_query($dbc, $query)or die('Error querying database');

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)){
    // ...
}
```

Comment: It's better to open it once and close it when you're all done. Sounds like you need to configure the MySQL server. How much traffic is there on the site?

Comment: Please show us how you open the connection

Comment: I have up to 3,000 page view per day of which around 1,350 are unique

Comment: Have you read this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/9391741/1839439

Comment: That's nothing for MySQL. If you had 3000 per second, I could imagine it might be an issue. Check the link from @Dharman. My bet it that some connections doesn't close properly.

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson, agreed, my hits are not the cause of the problem.  Appreciate your help.

Comment: I will take a good look at the post above, thanks @Dharman.  I will also make sure I close every page connection with mysqli_close($con), rather than letting it take care of itself once my php script has fully executed.  Appreciate your help